# how to reuse result from sub query in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery

When working on a mobile project with SQLite, I encountered a query similar to the following code:

```
SELECT col_aa, col_ab FROM tbl_a
WHERE col_ac IN (SELECT col_ba FROM tbl_b WHERE col_bb IN (SELECT col_ca FROM tbl_c WHERE col_cb = 1))
AND col_ad IN (SELECT col_ba FROM tbl_b WHERE col_bb IN (SELECT col_ca FROM tbl_c WHERE col_cb = 1))
```

It is quite obvious that those subqueries are redundant and wasteful.

After some research, it seem that the CTE, common table expression, might be a solution, but that feature is not available on SQLite. (thus, I am not sure if the WITH temp AS statement will work or not)

Is there a better way to restructure the query to reuse the result from the sub query?

Comment: In SQLite, I usually insert my subquery data in a temp table. but unless your query is really very expensive, it doesn't worth effort. If only a single row is needed, you can use fake `JOIN`s to keep data in current dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `tbl_b.col_ba` is a primary key (or just unique field) simple `JOIN` should help. Try this SQL:

```
SELECT 
  col_aa, 
  col_ab 
FROM 
  tbl_a JOIN
    (
      SELECT col_ba 
      FROM tbl_b 
      WHERE col_bb IN 
       (
         SELECT col_ca 
         FROM tbl_c 
         WHERE col_cb = 1
       )
    ) T2 ON (col_ac = T2.col_ba AND col_ad = T2.col_ba)
```

Hope it will help

Comment: when join tables this way, it only returns rows where col_ac = col_ad.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a view, like below.... (sorry the code is untested)

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS 
SELECT col_ba FROM tbl_b WHERE col_bb IN (SELECT col_ca FROM tbl_c WHERE col_cb = 1)

SELECT col_aa, col_ab FROM tbl_a
WHERE col_ac IN (SELECT col_ba FROM my_view)
AND col_ad IN (SELECT col_ba FROM my_view)
```